# two seperate websites but I want one to rank quicker

Tags: 301-redirect, social-media

I want to get a site I've had a while rank quicker, it is http://socialmediamarketingthailand.com being a social media marketer in Thailand. It's been up a while but I've not had much content on a free template.

I also own http://internetmediathailand.com and this is on page one Google for 'social media marketing bangkok' keyword search.

I have since spent a lot of time making http://socialmediamarketingthailand.com a lot nicer and with new content, and http://internetmediathailand.com is looking old yet has the ranking.

If I redirect Internet media to the newer fresher socialmedia site will I get anywhere quicker?

Answer (score 1):

How long has the new site been live for? It can take up to three months for all of Google to take notice.

I would be patient. The site that has more quality content and more of it will always win in the end.

Comment: Hi ewakened thanks for the reply Socialmediamarketingthailand has been up around 3 years but Ive only just started filling out the content Internetmediathailand is about the smae age